# Error when accessing from browser to apache web server via https using CA

Tags: apache, ssl, https, debian, ca

#### What I need

I have two Debian 11 machines, I want one to be a Apache server and I want the other one to be a CA (Certification Authority). Both servers resolve the hostname of each other.

- Server 1 user: webadmin
- Server 1 name: web
- Server 2 user: caadmin
- Server 2 name: ca

When I try to access from a web browser of a client that also resolve both hostnames (web and ca) and has also installed the ca certificate, I get the following errors (I tried from W11, Debian and MacOS clients so I think adding the ca certificate to the client is not the problem):

- Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
- Firefox: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I just want to visualize my website via https without any warning and trusting the server certificate as it should be trusted due to having the CA certificate installed: https://web

I'd really appreciate someone's help to solve this scenario.

#### What I did

I sucessfully installed apache2 on the web server, and enabled `mod_ssl` and `default-ssl.conf` site.

From `ca` I created a demo CA to sign certificates:

```
cd /usr/lib/ssl/misc
./CA.pl -newca
```

From `web` I created my own certificate (setting my FQDN to "web") and I sent it to ca:

```
cd /usr/lib/ssl/misc
./CA.pl -newreq-nodes
scp newreq.pem caadmin@ca:/usr/lib/ssl/misc
```

From `ca` I signed it and sent it back with the ca certificate:

```
./CA.pl -sign
scp newcert.pem webadmin@web:/etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
scp cacert.pem webadmin@web:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.crt
```

From `web` I installed the ca certificate and located my keys in `default-ssl.conf`

```
update-ca-certificates
cp newkey.pem /etc/ssl/private/priv.key
```

And this is my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webadmin@web
        ServerName web
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ssl
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/priv.key
        SSLVerifyClient None
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And I located my html in the DocumentRoot.

Comment: The error you see occurs if the domain in the URL does not match a subject alternative name in your certificate. Unfortunately both information about the URL you use to access the site and  the content of the certificate configured for the site are missing in your question.

Comment: When you use CA.pl -newreq-nodes there is an entry to specify the common name, I specify "web".

Comment: *"there is an entry to specify the common name"* - common name is not sufficient today, one needs subject alternative names.  I don't think that CA.pl can do this, but there are lots of instructions on the internet on how to create certificates with subject alternative names with openssl.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much! You were right!